# SSH key will not permanently add to my keychain

Tags: ssh, macos-sierra

I have tried the following:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This seems to work until I end my terminal session, but then I get prompted for my passphrase again with a new session.

Here is what I see after running the command above:

```
Identity added: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

I am on `iTerm2 Build 3.0.13` with `zsh: stable 5.3.1` running on `macOS Sierra 10.12.2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to add the command in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file. Then every time you open a new terminal the command will be executed automatically.
Since you are using `zsh` you need to add the command in `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` file.

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa &> /dev/null
```

The `&> /dev/null` is to avoid seeing the `Identity added` message everytime you open a new terminal window.

Comment: Sajib, I edited your answer as I think you missed that I was using zsh. Thanks the solution works.

Comment: Yes. I missed `zsh`. Welcome.

Comment: I can confirm that this is also solution for macOS High Sierra. My problem was ssh-add -A doesn't add to keychain.So every time I have to run ssh-add -K path/to/key

Answer (score 5):

Can try `ssh-add -K` again or edit your `~/.ssh/config` to enable the option:

`Host *
    UseKeychain yes`

If `ssh-add` states could not connect, try setting it up with:

`eval $(ssh-agent)`

Similar to: 
https://superuser.com/a/1158050

Comment: I think the issue was not having `UseKeychain yes` in my ssh config file. I have updated that and confirmed that the key was added using `ssh-add -l`

Comment: Hey, I am being asked for my ssh passphrase again. So this did not appear to fix my issue as I has assumed. Removing the check/tick to encourage other answers. Very frustrated.